# If the user is within the bounds of the map, show location; if not, show map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I show a map of a specific location, with points of interest pinned on the map. This is already accomplished... 
What I am looking to do is to add the following functionality: 
If the user is located WITHIN the existing bounds of this map, show the users current location zoomed in at 10 with these pins in place. If the user is NOT within the bounds of the map, just show the map with the points of interest pins.

I have included a portion of my code that will either show the users location, regardless of the existing bounds of the map OR show just the bounds without a users location. you will see that i have been playing around with the functionality and getting nowhere.

```
GeoMarker = new GeolocationMarker();
GeoMarker.setCircleOptions({fillColor: '#808080',fillOpacity:0.0,strokeOpacity:0.0});

google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(GeoMarker, 'position_changed', function() {
map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
//map.fitBounds(this.getBounds()); //uncomment to show based on user location regardless of the exsisting bounds of the map
//map.fitBounds(bounds); //uncomment to show ALL the listing Markers within the bounds of the map and not location of the user
//if (map.getZoom() > 1) map.setZoom(13); //this zoom is based on user location
// map.setCenter(this.getPosition());


var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() { 
google.maps.event.removeListener(listener); 
});
});

google.maps.event.addListener(GeoMarker, 'geolocation_error', function(e) {
alert('There was an error obtaining your position. Message: ' + e.message);
});
GeoMarker.setMap(map); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if I understood your problem correctly, but you can obtain the bounds of your current viewport via google.maps.Map.getBounds() which returns a [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=de#LatLngBounds) object. On this call the contains()-method passing the coordinates of your user to check if your user is within the bounds or not.